# Display a message under certain criteria instead of results in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

In Kusto, I want to display a message to the user depending on certain criteria. For example

```
isempty(['_tenant'])
| print "Note: ", "You must select a tenant"

else???

Events
| where tenant == ['_tenant']
| ...
```

The criteria is different for each query, as well as the message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You gave no context, and this request doesn't seem to make much sense. There are things that should be done on the client side, whatever it is in your case.

Answer (score 1):

A different way to do it is to do a union where each leg of the union is mutually exclusive. The catch is that a function must return a consistent schema regardless of input. So you'll end up with both a Status column and an x column in this example.

```
let myFunc = (y:long) {
    union 
    (
        print Status = "Y must be greater than 0"
        | where y > 0
    ),
    (
        range x from 1 to 10 step 1
        | where y <= 0
    )        
};
myFunc(-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be looking for the assert() function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/assert-function

```
let checkLength = (len:long, s:string)
{
    assert(len > 0, "Length must be greater than zero") and
    strlen(s) > len
};
datatable(input:string)
[
    '123',
    '4567'
]
| where checkLength(len=long(-1), input)
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, but I don't like the fact that it throws a big red error. I want to give something more informative than making the user think something is broken. Will still consider this, thanks.